# configuring jdk1.4 & jdk1.5 on a linux machine

Tags: linux, jboss, amazon-web-services, java-5, java-home

My web application must run on Jboss3.2.3 and jdk1.4.2_19. I have another java application (X) that requires jdk1.5 on the same machine (AMI Linux). So I need to set my JAVA_HOME to 2 java versions

I'm trying to address the issue as follows:

set my JAVA_HOME and default java (/usr/bin/java) to jdk1.5 to run my java app . X
change Jboss' run.sh file to make JAVA_HOME variable to point to jdk1.4

Have anyone had tried to change  Jboss' run.sh to point to another Java version (jdk1.4 in my case)? Any pointer/suggestions please?

I look forward to your thoughts

Thanks in advance
NK